# X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest with Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheet for a service we use to import all the data on it, but recently service providers upgraded their system including X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest in their header, now we are stuck because the app script is showing blank.

We are using the following script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/master/ImportJSON.gs

Can anyone guide how to request " X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest " with the above script?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `ImportJSONBasicAuth` function as follows:

```
function ImportJSONBasicAuth(url, username, password, query, parseOptions) {
  var encodedAuthInformation = Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);
  var header = {headers: {
   Authorization: "Basic " + encodedAuthInformation,
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" 
  }};
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, header, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```